# removing some special columns in large data set with R

Tags: r

I work with large data set(1200*10000),in my data sets some columns have a same value except in one or two point, I need to detect and delete this columns, for example in column “1846”:

```
> x[317:400,1846]

 [1] 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2

[81] 2 2 **1** 2
```

Other row values(1:317 and 400:1200)=2.

How can I solve this?

For example in some part of My file (1200*10000),

```
x
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12]
 [1,]    1    1    0    1    2    0    1    0    1     2     2     1
 [2,]    1    1    0    1    2    0    1    0    1     2     1     1
 [3,]    2    1    0    1    2    0    1    0    1     2     2     1
 [4,]    1    2    0    1    2    0    1    0    1     2     2     2
 [5,]    0    1    0    1    2    0    1    0    1     2     1     1
 [6,]    2    0    0    1    2    0    1    2    0     2     1     2
 [7,]    1    1    0    1    2    1    1    0    1     2     0     2
 [8,]    0    1    0    1    2    0    1    0    1     2     0     0
 [9,]    0    1    0    1    2    0    1    0    1     1     2     1
[10,]    1    1    0    1    2    0    1    0    1     2     1     1
```

I want to remove in my original data set columns like 3 to 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not certain, but I think you want to delete any columns that contain a single value in `n-1` or `n-2` rows where `n` is the number of rows.  If so, then you would want to delete:

column `x2` in `my.data` because it contains 9 '1's and one '0' and

column `x5` in `my.data` because it contains 8 '2's and two '1's.

The code below does that.  Sorry if this is not what you are trying to do.  I am not sure whether this code would perform well with a huge data frame.

```
my.data <- read.table(text='

x1  x2  x3  x4  x5  x6
 1   1   2   2   2   1
 1   1   2   1   1   2
 1   1   2   2   2   3
 1   1   2   2   2   4
 1   1   2   1   2   5
 1   1   2   2   2   6
 1   0   2   2   2   7
 1   1   2   1   2   8
 1   1   2   2   1   9
 1   1   2   2   2  10

', header = TRUE)

my.data

my.summary <- as.data.frame.matrix(table( rep(colnames(my.data), 
                      each=nrow(my.data)), unlist(my.data)))
my.summary

delete.these <- which(my.summary == (nrow(my.data)-2) | 
                      my.summary == (nrow(my.data)-1), arr.ind = TRUE)[,1]

my.data[,-delete.these]

   x1 x3 x4 x6
1   1  2  2  1
2   1  2  1  2
3   1  2  2  3
4   1  2  2  4
5   1  2  1  5
6   1  2  2  6
7   1  2  2  7
8   1  2  1  8
9   1  2  2  9
10  1  2  2 10
```

Answer (score 1):

Continue from my answer in your first post,

```
detect.col <- function(
  x,
  n.diff=3 # the minimal  number of unique values required per column
  )
{
  ret <- which(apply(x,2,function(e){length(unique(e))}) >= n.diff)
  ret  
}

x[,detect.col(x)]
```

I guess this is what you actually mean?

Comment: @MartínBel, I think he had previous questions and he need columns with all 0,1 and 2 and this is just subset.

Comment: I "guess" what to be excluded are those columns have less than 3 unique values (0, 1 and 2 in this case). I wait for @Rahmani86 to clarify it.

Comment: @MartínBel NO!! Excuse me misunderstanding occurred, I’m not look for x <- x[,-(3:10)],
I mean how can I detect (and then delete) in large file, column like this ,3 to 10.

Comment: @xb In fist step,I searching for columns 100% identical,like columns 3,4,5
And 2ns step, columns in one or 2 point different like  columne 6,8,9,10

Comment: @Rahmani86, you are welcome. I edited my answer in your **first** post (linked on the top of this post) and add the "n.diff" option there. set n.diff=3 to get columns 3,4,5,7 and n.diff=2 to get columns 3-10. BTW, it will be a good habit to edit/complete your question in your original post instead of initialize a new one :)

Comment: @xb Thank you so much,Execuseme for irregularity of my Questions, I am beginner in R and "Stackoverflow".

Answer (score 1):

```
mm<-read.table(text="      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12]
 [1,]    1    1    0    1    2    0    1    0    1     2     2     1
 [2,]    1    1    0    1    2    0    1    0    1     2     1     1
 [3,]    2    1    0    1    2    0    1    0    1     2     2     1
 [4,]    1    2    0    1    2    0    1    0    1     2     2     2
 [5,]    0    1    0    1    2    0    1    0    1     2     1     1
 [6,]    2    0    0    1    2    0    1    2    0     2     1     2
 [7,]    1    1    0    1    2    1    1    0    1     2     0     2
 [8,]    0    1    0    1    2    0    1    0    1     2     0     0
 [9,]    0    1    0    1    2    0    1    0    1     1     2     1
[10,]    1    1    0    1    2    0    1    0    1     2     1     1", row.names=1, header=T)
```

now,

```
mm[,which(apply(mm,2,function (x) {length(unique(x))})==3)
```

output

```
      X..1. X..2. X..11. X..12.
[1,]      1     1      2      1
[2,]      1     1      1      1
[3,]      2     1      2      1
[4,]      1     2      2      2
[5,]      0     1      1      1
[6,]      2     0      1      2
[7,]      1     1      0      2
[8,]      0     1      0      0
[9,]      0     1      2      1
[10,]     1     1      1      1
```

Answer (score 0):

This will keep only columns with one distinct value, assuming your `data.frame` is named `x`:

```
keepIndex <- apply(
    x, 
    2, 
    FUN = function(column) {
        return(length(unique(column)) == 1)
    })

x <- x[, keepIndex]
```

Answer (score 0):

This Should work,

```
m<-matrix(2,nrow=100, ncol=100)  #making dummy matrix m  
m[sample(1:100,10), sample(1:100,10)]<-1       #replacing some random row and col to 1
m[,-which(colSums(m==1)>0)]     #getting rid of cols with 1
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution based on Boolean indexing.

```
> x<-cbind(c(1,1,1,1),c(1,1,1,2),c(1,1,1,1))
> x
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    1    1
[2,]    1    1    1
[3,]    1    1    1
[4,]    1    2    1
> x[,colSums(x!=x[1,])==0]
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    1
[2,]    1    1
[3,]    1    1
[4,]    1    1
```

Answer (score 0):

If your data is stored in a data frame named `df`:

```
df[ ,sapply(df, function(x) all(x[1] == x[-1]))]
```

Answer (score 0):

Either search the whole data or a subset of it:

```
detect.col <- function(
  x,row.from=1,row.to=nrow(x),col.from=1,col.to=ncol(x),
  n.diff=3 # the minimal number of unique values required per column
  )
{
  tmp.x <- x[row.from:row.to,col.from:col.to]
  ret <- which(apply(tmp.x,2,function(e){length(unique(e))}) < n.diff )
  if(length(ret)){
    ret <- ret+col.from-1
  }
  ret  
}

## search the whole
detect.col(x) # columns to remove

## Or only search within a range, like in your case
row.from <- 317
row.to <- 400

col.from <- 1000
col.to <- 2000

col.to.remove <- detect.col(x,row.from,row.to,col.from,col.to)
x[,-col.to.remove] # print those to keep
```

Comment: I've merged the two questions now - you might want to consolidate your answers perhaps?